Leaking shower--wet wood and mold. Will applying new waterproofing over exposed areas be sufficient?
I have a shower leak in my upstairs shower due to improper waterproofing--we've had sporadic water damage in the downstairs ceiling since the shower install two years ago with various attempts to fix. The contractor removed the curb to find that the curb has no lining or waterproofing at all. The liner basically stopped at the curb. The wood under the curb is soaked and extends under the lining in the shower floor. It's black but I haven't tested for mold type.
The contractor says that if they properly seal the curb, the leak will stop, the mold will be contained and can no longer get wet, which will solve the issue.
Is this a valid assertion, or do I need to insist that the floor be redone? Since it's two years since install on a one-year warranty, they are balking, but they'll fix the curb.

I would at least want the mold sprayed with bleach and the wood checked for rot.  This is the minimum.  Some black mold is a major health concern(as get out now) and should be tested for type.  Two piece water sealing to done right or might as well forget it.

The argument
the curb has no lining or waterproofing at all.
The leaking started on day one (during the warranty)

I agree with the timing.
